# How do I initialize the mutex locks and condition variables

Tags: c++, pthreads, posix

pthread_mutex_t qlock[5] = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

pthread_cond_t qcond[5] =   PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

It is giving me error as follows...

error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer

.. Please, can somebody debug this or tell me a way to solve it...

Comment: You have asked 14 questions and accepted no answers! It's impossible you did not get a single decent answer to all these questions - please go over your questions and acknowledge the time and effort other people have put in answering them!

Comment: how do I accept the answers???.. I am new to this group..

Comment: @Invictus See the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) but the short version is click on the check box next to the answer that best answers your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This initializes a mutex:

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

This initializes an array:

```
int array[5] = { 0, 1, 2, 3,  4 };
```

...that should be enough to get you going.

Comment: We can do for the mutex lock, but, what about condition variable??

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you reading a beginner book on C programming language. See for example a [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

BTW, at this level of C knowledge I would *highly* recommend you to stay away from multithreaded programming (at least with pthreads).